# BeautifulSoup soup object creation consistent error

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new in web scraping, and I ma having a few difficulties using beautifulsoup, which seems more related to installation than to the code itself. I have installed bs4, and want to get data from webpages. I started with a simple exercise as follows:

```
import requests
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=37.7772&lon=-122.4168")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

which gets me the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-62-a9912850b0dc>", line 1, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

  File "/Users/../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1522, in __init__
    BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1147, in __init__
    self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)

  File "/Users/../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1189, in _feed
    SGMLParser.feed(self, markup)

  File "/Users/../anaconda/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 104, in feed
    self.goahead(0)

  File "/Users/../anaconda/lib/python2.7/sgmllib.py", line 174, in goahead
    k = self.parse_declaration(i)

  File "/Users/../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1463, in parse_declaration
    j = SGMLParser.parse_declaration(self, i)

  File "/Users/../anaconda/lib/python2.7/markupbase.py", line 109, in parse_declaration
    self.handle_decl(data)

  File "/Users/../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1448, in handle_decl
    self._toStringSubclass(data, Declaration)

  File "/Users/../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1381, in _toStringSubclass
    self.endData(subclass)

  File "/Users/../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1251, in endData
    (not self.parseOnlyThese.text or \

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

If I remove `'html.parser`' and use

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
```

the code works, but, of course, it does not give me what I need.

Any clues as to how to solve this? I am in a OSX El Capitan, and use spyder as editor. I did re-installed bs4 a few times.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old version of BeautifulSoup. Please uninstall it, and then install BeautifulSoup4, with `pip install BeautifulSoup4`; and then adjust your code thus:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=37.7772&lon=-122.4168')
s = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thanks Khalid. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this snippet:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
# in place of page.content use page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```